# Use gsub to replace curly apostrophe with straight apostrophe in R list of character vectors

Tags: r, special-characters, text-mining, gsub

Looking for some guidance on how to replace a curly apostrophe with a straight apostrophe in an R list of character vectors.

The reason I'm replacing the curly apostrophes - later in the script, I check each list item, to see if it's found in a dictionary (using qdapDictionary) to ensure it's a real word and not garbage.  The dictionary uses straight apostrophes, so words with the curly apostrophes are being "rejected."

A sample of the code I have currently follows.  In my test list, item #6 contains a curly apostrophe, and item #2 has a straight apostrophe.

Example:

```
list_TestWords <- as.list(c("this", "isn't", "ideal", "but", "we", "can’t", "fix", "it"))

func_ReplaceTypographicApostrophes <- function(x) {
   gsub("’", "'", x, ignore.case = TRUE)
 }

list_TestWords_Fixed <- lapply(list_TestWords, func_ReplaceTypographicApostrophes)
```

The result:  No change.  Item 6 still using curly apostrophe.  See output below.

```
list_TestWords_Fixed
[[1]]
[1] "this"

[[2]]
[1] "isn't"

[[3]]
[1] "ideal"

[[4]]
[1] "but"

[[5]]
[1] "we"

[[6]]
[1] "can’t"

[[7]]
[1] "fix"

[[8]]
[1] "it"
```

Any help you can offer will be most appreciated!

Comment: Try `gsub("’", "'", x, fixed=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Wiktor.  Didn't work, but would welcome additional suggestions!

Comment: Additional: `gsub("(*UCP)’", "'", x, perl=TRUE)` or just `gsub("’", "'", x, perl=TRUE)`. Note that `ignore.case = TRUE` can be safely removed.

Comment: Tried each of these modifications, to no avail. :( . Could it have something to do with the structure of my list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be running up against a [bug in R](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17329) on Windows. Try using `utf8::as_utf8` on your input. Alternatively, this also works:

```
library(utf8)
list_TestWords <- as.list(c("this", "isn't", "ideal", "but", "we", "can’t", "fix", "it"))
lapply(list_TestWords, utf8_normalize, map_quote = TRUE)
```

This will replace the following characters with ASCII apostrophe:

```
U+055A ARMENIAN APOSTROPHE
U+2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
U+201B SINGLE HIGH-REVERSED-9 QUOTATION MARK
U+FF07 FULLWIDTH APOSTROPHE
```

It will also convert your text to composed normal form (NFC).

Comment: Seems as though `utf_normalize` and `as_utf8` are in `utf8` package now.

Answer (score 3):

This might work: `gsub("[\u2018\u2019\u201A\u201B\u2032\u2035]", "'", x)`

I found it over here: http://axonflux.com/handy-regexes-for-smart-quotes

Answer (score 1):

I see a problem in your call to `gsub`:

```
gsub("/’", "/'", x, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

You are prefixing the curly single quote with a forward slash.  I don't  know why you are doing this.  I could speculate that you are trying to escape the quote characters, but this is having the side effect that your pattern is now trying to match a forward slash followed by a quote.  As this never occurs in your text, no replacements are being made. You should be doing this:

```
gsub("’", "'", x, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

Follow the link below for a demo which shows that using the above `gsub` calls works as you expect.

## Demo

Comment: Thanks Tim, just made that adjustment in my script (and in the question) - but the function still isn't replacing the curly apostrophe.  Any other ideas?

Comment: It's often easier to include the thing to replace in a character class, so the first argument to `gsub` becomes `"[’]"`

Comment: @SarahWeaver My suggested code works in the demo which is using R version `3.3.2`.

Comment: @JDL We might use a character class for several reasons.  One is because we have a class of characters to represent in a regex pattern.  Another is that we want to avoid escaping a regex metacharacter.  Neither of these cases really apply here.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen - just tried your demo function on the test list, and it worked - but when I apply the same function to my "real" list, it didn't. Could this have something to do with the structure of the list? When I apply the function to an item from my real list (list_CorpusWords) it doesn't change the apostrophe - but when I enter the word itself into the function, it does.  Any thoughts? Example:

list_CorpusWords[1304]
$word
[1] "isn’t"
> func_ReplaceTypographicApostrophes(list_CorpusWords[1304])
[1] "isn’t"
> list_CorpusWords[1304]
$word
[1] "isn’t"

Answer (score 0):

Was about to say the same thing.

Try using `str_replace` from `stringr` package, will not need to use slashes

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem. Somehow non of the solutions worked for me. So I devised an indirect way of doing it by identifying apostrophe and replacing it with the required format.

```
gsub("(\\w)(\\W)(\\w\\s)", "\\1'\\3","sid’s bicycle")
[1] "sid's bicycle"
```

Hope it helps someone.